# CSS Max Height Property

Tags: overflow, css

Is there a good **cross-browser** way to set a `max-height` property of a DIV and when that DIV goes beyond the `max-height`, it turns into an overflow with scrollbars?

Comment: could you not just set the height to be your max height and set the `overflow: scroll;` ?

Comment: @Jason That works using a static height e.g. 200px.  However, if your height is a percentage e.g. 100%, then overflowing content will override the specified height and just stretch element instead of clipping it or introducing scrollbars.

Answer (score 35):

Sadly IE6 doesn't so you have to use an expression for IE6, then set the max-height for all other browsers:

```
 div{
       _height: expression( this.scrollHeight > 332 ? "333px" : "auto" ); /* sets max-height for IE6 */
       max-height: 333px; /* sets max-height value for all standards-compliant browsers */
       overflow:scroll;
}
```

Overflow:auto would most likely work in most cases for have any extra spill over.

Comment: There is a problem with this... it generates a warning on IE6 about active content.

Comment: i have never used visual studio, but the css expression() is unique to internet explorer so i would hope their dev tools would recognize it.

Comment: overflow:auto and overflow-x:hidden FTW!! :) thanks for the fix

Comment: I tried doing this on a Dashboard UI I was building in jQuery and experienced serious lag in IE... Beware of performance issues.

Comment: make sure you are only using it for the IE version you have to have it for.  IE 6 isn't the finest rendering engine performance wise so it should have issues in a lot of places.

Comment: alternatively we could stop supporting IE 6

Comment: I have today found a problem with this widespread solution: Due to some kind of browser timing/load issues, the expression is not always evaluated. Hitting CTRL-F5 to ensure refresh result in about 50% success rate... I'd support a ban of IE6!

Answer (score 16):

I found this solution from a post made in 2005 ([Min-Height Fast hack](http://www.dustindiaz.com/min-height-fast-hack/)). It's a hack but it's simple and pure CSS:

```
selector {
  max-height:500px;
  height:auto !important;
  height:500px;
}
```

The example is for max-height, but it works for min-height, min-width and max-width. :)

*Note: You must use absolute values, percentages don't work.

All you need now is the "overflow:scroll;" to make this work with scroll bars

Comment: This only works in IE6 (the only browser that needs a hack at all anymore for this) for `min-width/height`, *not* `max-width/height`.

Comment: Correction (from the spec): _"The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block."_ as such, the parent must have a height set in order for min/max-height (or width) to be used.

Answer (score 8):

```
selector
{
    max-height:900px;
    _height:expression(this.scrollHeight>899?"900px":"auto");
    overflow:auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Anyone else try this one with success?

Answer (score 1):

Could you have a wrapper div with the height set as your height and overflow: scrolling.  Then the inner div has no height set and as it grows it will fill then use the scrollbars of the first div?

Comment: Good thought, but it still requires setting a base height to more than he wants for a block level element.  Otherwise, he'd just set that height on the element he's really concerned with.

Answer (score 0):

Major hack (RedWolves-style):

```
.divMax{width:550px;height:200px;overflow-Y:auto;position:absolute;}
.divInner{border:1px solid navy;background-color:white;}
```

I was getting no love from the max-height attribute so I had this alreadyand succeeded with these 2 classes.  But it's ugly so in searching for better hit this question. divMax having `position:absolute` lets content underneath show through but controls the ultimate height of divInner to 200px.

Answer (score -1):

I found this from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_scrollbars.htm and modified a bit. It seems working for both IE9 and FF19

```
<style type="text/css">
.scroll{
    display:block;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding:5px;
    margin-top:5px;
    width:300px;

    max-height:100px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
.auto{
    display:block;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding:5px;
    margin-top:5px;
    width:300px;
    height: 100px !important;
    max-height:110px;
    overflow:hidden;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
</style>
<p>Example of scroll value:</p>

<div class="scroll">
    I am going to keep lot of content here just to show
    you how scrollbars works if there is an overflow in
    an element box. This provides your horizontal as well
     as vertical scrollbars.<br/>
    I am going to keep lot of content here just to show
    you how scrollbars works if there is an overflow in
    an element box. This provides your horizontal as well
     as vertical scrollbars.<br/>
    I am going to keep lot of content here just to show
    you how scrollbars works if there is an overflow in
    an element box. This provides your horizontal as well
     as vertical scrollbars.<br/>
    I am going to keep lot of content here just to show
    you how scrollbars works if there is an overflow in
    an element box. This provides your horizontal as well
     as vertical scrollbars.<br/>        
     </div>

<br />
<p>Example of auto value:</p>

<div class="auto">
    I am going to keep lot of content here just to show
    you how scrollbars works if there is an overflow in
    an element box. This provides your horizontal as well
     as vertical scrollbars.<br/>
   </div>
```