# How can I create a DIV that expands UP TO a height and then shows a scrollbar?

Tags: css, html, overflow

I am trying to implement a `DIV` which contains some text, and behaves the following way:

- Fixed width (500px)
- Capped height (Up to 400 px)

  1. If the text renders to <400px (say, 100px tall), the containing DIV is as much height as text (100px in our example).
  2. If the text renders to >400px, the containing div is only 400px in height, and oveflow is handled via a vertical scrollbar in the DIV.

I know how to implement #2 (`overflow: auto; position: relative`) but that behavior depends on having `height=400px` which of course negates #1 desired behavior.

How can this be achieved via CSS?

I'd prefer a reasonably cross-platform soluion, if that's too hard, must work on IE7, IE8 and FireFox 10+.

Comment: @c0d3Junk13 - as I tried to communicate via tags, only pure CSS

Comment: @c0d3Junk13 - you can. See my comment to his answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try a combination of [`max-height`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/max-height) and `overflow: auto;`.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ysbL7/1/).

Comment: This doesn't work on IE6. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/297802/119280 for making IE6 compliant version

Comment: True, but you didn't specify it had to work on IE6, just IE7. Also, why are you still supporting IE6? Even Microsoft doesn't support it anymore. Thanks for the accept by the way!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `max-height` property rather than `height`, but it won't work in IE6, which doesn't respect *any* min/max properties.

If IE6 usage is a must, you will have to fall back on Javascript (the only other method is with IE's proprietary CSS expressions, but they're very poor-performance and rely on JS to be enabled anyway).

Comment: You can use the method from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/297802/119280) which is what I've ended up doing

Comment: @DVK - you may as well use javascript, as expressions only work if JS is enabled, and JS is a much better solution as CSS expressions can be a performance liability if improperly used. They actually get evaluated *whenever the user moves their mouse over the page*, so they're very inefficient.