# how to determine number of line td will increase in codebehind in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html-table

i am generating td in codebehide using string str ="";
and then concentrating it.

string str="";

string msg="Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello HelloHello Hello Hello Hello HelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHello HelloHello HelloHello HelloHelloVV";

+msg+

I am generating td in codebehind
if i reduced the length of string msg then height of td reduces and if i increase the string length of string msg then height of that td increase. Actually I want whenever the td has two line of text ,I want a scroll bar sbould be appear to my uppermost div.The data in the td is coming from database ,it can be of any size.also there can be n number of td (its dynamic).I want srollbar in uppermost div .

For this i had done some RND as

```
//first i have find how much lengh the first line can take 
//let say 200 then i have check 

if(len>400)
{
    divid.Attributes.Add("style", "height:50px;overflow:auto;");
}
```

Its giving me what i want but in some cases it fails ,this is not 100% solution .I Want a 100% solution.I want to determine number of line td will increase .Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of computing td height yourself, you can ask your client browser to do it. This is better because on different webbrowsers and different font size your TD can have different height. Use CSS or JavaScript to add scrollbar. For example, you can try to use CSS max-height and overflow properties on your div (always, without checking for length, for example using CSS class). Check here [CSS Max Height Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297686/css-max-height-property) for some variants.

Example

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .myDiv {
           max-height: 3em;
           overflow-y: auto;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="myDiv">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
             My line of code<br>
             My line of code<br>
             My line of code
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S. And better use StringBuilder when concatenating strings. It would work more efficiently.

Comment: But i am generating html in codebehind and td generation is dynamic mean td can be n number(2,3,4 any number)and whenever the td has two line of text i want srollbar on the uppermost div

Comment: my html generating in codebehind is as folllow                             let say <div><table><tr><td> dynamic data comes here </td></tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td> dynamic data comes here </td></tr></table></div>                                             i want scroll on div.if 1st,2nd,3rd td has 2 line then i dont want sroll and if 1st td has 2line and 2nd has 3line then i want sroll on div.how can i do

Comment: I've updated the answer with example and more explanation. Please accept it if it is useful.

Comment: But your example show only one td, but in my case there can be n number of td.and also the data in the td is coming from database.if all td has only 2line then i dont want scrollbar and if any one of them has 3lines then only i want scroll on the div.

Comment: if i use    max-height: XXem;overflow-y: auto; and if all the td has only two line and if max height exeed then i wll be getting scroll .But in this case i dont want scroll only in case any of the td has 3line i want scroll.

Comment: If you *really* has such illogical and strange requirement ("if any one of them has 3lines then only i want scroll on the div") then you should use JavaScript. I recommend jQuery. But I think you just misunderstood what they require of you.

Comment: Yes I know its strange.But using javascript or jquery how will i come to know whether the td has 3line or 2line.                     $(tdid)

Comment: its done but i want to set height in percent ,when am setting it pixel i am getting a scroll but i want to set it in percent

Comment: Why don't you want to set it in `em`? 1 em equals height of one row in the current font, so they are more flexible than pixels (when font size changes, em also changes).