# jQuery autocomplete result should appear like combo box

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

The response has about 500 records and it looks ugly in auto-complete. If more than 10 suggestion then is there any change make the list look like combobox instead of very long list?

Thanks

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#textbox_postcode').autocomplete(
            {
                source: 'search-db.php',
                minLength: 3
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="textbox_postcode" value="" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not just limit the height of the autocomplete dropdown?

Comment: now do you mean 'combo box' or something else? since jquery-ui use 'combo box' as a text input with an arrow for a dropdown list of the data. http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: If it has 10 suggestions leave it as is, if more than that then it shouldn't go beyond (e.g. 200px in heights) but should show rest of the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the following to your .css file.

```
.ui-autocomplete {
max-height: 100px !important;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

`max-height` can be whatever you would like.

Comment: yes can do, or your own style sheet, as long as they are linked to the page.

Comment: it does not work for IE6 and below but for IE7 and above it should work. for IE6 look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297686/css-max-height-property